# Can't remove files in container with entrypoint.sh

Tags: docker

I extended the official postgres-9.5 image to start pre-populated containers using a dump inside the image.
I extended the entrypoint.sh to execute some post-init commands aimed at removing the heavy dump.

```
postgres
total 427632
drwxr-xr-x  2 postgres postgres      4096 May  1 15:46 .
drwxr-xr-x 59 root     root          4096 May  1 15:54 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 postgres postgres 437876014 Apr 27 07:42 dump.sql
-rw-rw-r--  1 postgres postgres       236 Apr 27 20:20 init-user-db.sh
rm: cannot remove ‘/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/’: Permission denied
```

However I don't understand why my part is failing, maybe it's due to Docker internal mechanics that makes it read-only during this stage, even from the owner of the files (first line is a whoami)... but if I go root with docker exec I can remove them manually.

It's not a blocking issue, but I can't find any documentation answering me.

Edit:
As requested, here is what I added to the entrypoint to get the output above

```
echo
echo 'PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.'
echo

# Cleanup => user=postgresql
whoami
ls -la /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
rm -rf /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
echo 'Removed init files'
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM postgres:9.5

LABEL maintainer "Hiruma"

ADD nightly-dump/ /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
ADD init-user-db.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-user-db.sh

RUN chown -R postgres:postgres /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]

EXPOSE 5432
CMD ["postgres"]
```

Comment: Can you post the exact code you added to the script? Have you verified that you do have permissions to delete it with `ls -lah` / `whoami`?

Comment: @kichik edited my question

Comment: Can you try: `rm -rf /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*` (with the star) just to see if it makes some difference

Comment: @Robert This is what I did first actually, the only difference is the message stating that I don't have the permissions on dump.sql and init-user-db.sh

Comment: How do you `COPY` the files? Can you please show the Dockerfile in order to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I use `ADD` and added the Dockerfile to the original question.